# Extracting p,d,q values from a fitted ARIMA model in R?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am running a time series forecast using `forecast::auto.arima`, and I was trying to see if there is a way to extract the values assigned to `p`, `d`, `q` (and seasonally as well if applicable) from the fitted time series object. Example:

```
fit <- auto.arima(mydata)
```

Say `auto.arima()` picked an `ARIMA(1,1,0)(0,1,1)[12]` model. Is there a way to extract the values of `p`,`d`, `q` (and `P`, `D`, `Q`) from fit?  In the end I would like to have six variables automatically assigned as follows:

```
p=1, d=1, q=0, P=0, D=1, Q=1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at `?auto.arima`, you will know that it returns the same object as `stats::arima`. If you further look at `?arima`, you see that the information you want can be found from `$model` of the returned value. The detail of `$model` can be read from `?KalmanLike`:

```
phi, theta: numeric vectors of length >= 0 giving AR and MA parameters.

     Delta: vector of differencing coefficients, so an ARMA model is
            fitted to ‘y[t] - Delta[1]*y[t-1] - ...’.
```

So, you should do:

```
p <- length(fit$model$phi)
q <- length(fit$model$theta)
d <- fit$model$Delta
```

Example from `?auto.arima`:

```
library(forecast)
fit <- auto.arima(WWWusage)

length(fit$model$phi)  ## 1
length(fit$model$theta)  ## 1
fit$model$Delta  ## 1

fit$coef
#       ar1       ma1 
# 0.6503760 0.5255959
```

**Alternatively (actually better)**, you can refer to the `$arma` value:

```
arma: A compact form of the specification, as a vector giving the
      number of AR, MA, seasonal AR and seasonal MA coefficients,
      plus the period and the number of non-seasonal and seasonal
      differences.
```

But you need to match them correctly and carefully. For the example above, there is:

```
fit$arma
# [1] 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
```

Using the notation `ARIMA(p,d,q)(P,D,Q)[m]`, we can add name attribute for clear presentation:

```
setNames(fit$arma, c("p", "q", "P", "Q", "m", "d", "D"))
# p q P Q m d D 
# 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks, the updated version is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: thanks I was looking for this definition! Initially I thought it was p,d,q,P,D,Q,m like in Statsmodel (Python)..

Answer (score 1):

A better, less hands-on, solution exists using the `forecast` package and the function `arimaorder()`. Apply this to the model and it returns the elements in the order you would expect:

```
> arimaorder(model1)
        p         d         q         P         D         Q Frequency 
        0         0         1         0         1         0        12
```